# Need help with new kitchen sink plumbing

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, faucet, sink

Just did my countertops and had new double sink installed. The new sink drains are not centered as before, but offset.  The installers took out the old one before I could take a picture of setup. The old setup had the garbage disposal installed on the left side.  With the plumbing that is in place now what will I need to get the two sinks up and running? I bought a new garbage disposal as well to install on the left side like before. Do I need major work done to get the plubming all sorted out or is this an easy fix with just extra pipes and some cutting and adjusting? If anyone can give me some feedback or diagram of how it should work for my situation that would be great. I'm attaching pictures of what I have right now. The new sink came with one drain assembly and one strainer. Please let me know what other parts I will need to complete the project.

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a pretty broad question... when routing the pipes, just keep in mind that water always has to move downwards.  If you run into any specific issues, we can help.  It looks like you have plenty of room to work, so you should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to mount your disposal so the outlet of the disposal can mate up with the pipe that's connected to the wall. It looks like it's currently positioned pretty close if you mount the disposal on the right. If you want it on the left then you'll probably need to shorten the pipe going into the wall and swing the trap around 180 degrees. The outlet of the disposal should point down and it will fit into the opening on the pipe that points up. The horizontal inlet that's on the pipe that's connected to the wall will conect to the pipe laying on the ground, the other end of that pipe will connect to the sink strainer.[image: New trap layout]

Comment: What about the pipe that is for the dishwasher air gap (sitting on the right side)? I know the white part will be above the counter with the metal cap, but what about the other end of it that has the metal clamp? Does it hook up to the garbage disposal inlet?

Comment: Yes, it hooks up to the garbage disposal inlet. Don't forget the inlet on the disposal probably has a knockout on it that you'll need to remove.

Comment: Which of the two drain parts should I install on other side of sink..the drain assembly (right side) or strainer (left)? Does it matter or either one will work with the plumbing underneath? The garbage disposal will gave it's own drain ring/assembly I assume. Also I saw in another video that the outlet from the garbage disposal was connected to the side of T connection whereas the drain tailpiece was connected to the top of that T-tube.  Does it make a difference?

Comment: Either strainer should work. If you had a deep and a shallow sink bowl then maybe it would be easier to plumb the disposal into the side of the T. When you lay it out keep in mind that you don't want waste any space under the cabinet and have access to the shut off valves without having to remove any pipes.

Comment: I visited my local Home Depot to get some materials to fix up the plumbing and the guy working in the plumbing department showed me a "Garbage Disposal Installation Kit". He informed me this had all the pieces I needed to install my garbage disposal and sink drain and dishwasher air gap. I just need to clear out the old tubes/pipes that was coming from the wall and start fresh. The old pipes that I had there were ABS, but this package is all white pipes. Is this Ok to use? Images are linked.   https://imgur.com/iLHk0p4   https://imgur.com/l0FtAId

Comment: Looks like you have already have everything you need and the disposal will come with a pipe to connect to the T. I would reuse existing and just get new slip washers, although that stuff is pretty inexpensive so no great expense to buy new.. You can mix ABS and PVC as long as the joints are mechanical and not glued.

Comment: So then I actually don't need that the new package with pipes and not have to remove exsisting and just try to see how everything will connect.  Also I've seen some setups where the garbage disposal is connected on the side inlet and the other drain connected on the top portion. Any difference here between these setups or in my case it should connect to the top from garbage disposal and drain to side inlet?  Should I also replace the flex supply lines since I am at it? Do they look in bad condition?

Comment: So I started to install the garbage disposal on the right side of sink and it looks like the outlet from garbage disposal is a big longer than the top of the inlet of the pipe that is there. This sink is about 3 inches deeper than my last sink (plus the disposal was on the left side). Also just eyeballing the other piece of tube that goes from drain to the side of the inlet it too seems to rather longer and might hit the top of the tube going towards the wall. Any suggestions on how to fix this issue? https://imgur.com/W0bSInW  https://imgur.com/BOvgvjt

Comment: Common problem with deep sinks. You may be able to find a disposal where the inlet is higher. If you can't you'll need to move the drain down. If you have questions on moving the drain you should start a new post. "Also just eyeballing the other piece of tube that goes from drain to the side of the inlet it too seems to rather longer and might hit the top of the tube going towards the wall." Should be able to cut it or swivel the fitting.

Comment: So I started to connect my disposable this way using tubes from the install kit. I know I have to cut the tailpiece about 4" so that outlet from disposable will reach the Tee. Also I need to cut the horizontal piece a bit to fit into the tee. So after doing that I would move the right side of drain up 4". However, it will still be sitting lower than P trap and will be short as well. Do I need to get an extension tube to extend the horizontal part of the P-trap and also trim off some of the Tee as well so that they can fit. https://imgur.com/y57c9pF

Comment: You should be able to get a longer extension tube so the p-trap reaches the Tee. If you can't get it to line up you may need to cut the pipe at the wall and extend it, if you do, avoid using a 90, use a 45.  Cut the bottom of the Tee as needed.

Comment: Do you think I should get another sink drain assembly since the one that came with my sink is much longer and plastic compared to the ones I see installed or at the stores. I think that might help a bit with the install as well.

Comment: The length of the strainer shouldn't be an issue and a different one may only be an inch shorter. Looks like you'll be fine cutting the tailpiece.

Comment: So looks like I will need to cut the tail piece on the right sink to raise the tee to proper height for disposal drain. Then cut the bottom of tee so trap is at correct height.  Then can I just add an extension piece on the 45 and then attach the horizontal piece/P-trap part to it to extend to reach the drain instead of cutting off the 45 at the main drain? I don't really want to mess with the main drain if I don't have to.

Comment: I would do this first - cut the tail piece on the right sink to raise the tee to proper height for disposal drain. I would do this next - add an extension piece on the 45 and then attach the horizontal piece/P-trap part to it to extend to reach the drain. Now you'll be able to see if the extension is at the right height and is close enough to where the trap can swivel and meet it. If it does you can now cut the bottom of the T. Hopefully it meets up fine and you can avoid cutting the drain.

Comment: Does the tube that goes from disposable inlet to the T have to be at a slight down incline and not perfectly horizontal?

Comment: Should slope down slightly, not level. Loosely connect the pipes, adjust, and then tighten.

Comment: So I finally got around to trying to put on the extension and based on the angle it is coming from the wall it still will not reach and align under my drain on the right side? Even cutting it down I don't will help here. What should I do next since this way it does not seem to work? Can I put another 45 degree on the exsisting 45 degree? Any suggestions will be appreciated. I am attaching pics of how it looks now with the extension.  https://imgur.com/a0AJoCy  https://imgur.com/G5c6iAQ  https://imgur.com/S2kmMFk

Comment: Looks like you'll need to redo the pipe coming out of the wall. If it's a 45 degree that's on there you can cut it off and put on a 22.5 degree and that might line up. If not then you can extend the pipe and use a 45 degree and that should line up. Pick up both and you should be able to eyeball it to see which works before  you cut anything.

Comment: So if I want to keep the wall pipe intact can I then add my extension to the 45 that is there, cut it, add another 45, add the horizontal arm/p trap and adjust it so that it will line up to drain. Of course I will need to cut extension to size so it can line up. Is that what you are suggesting?

Comment: Cut the pie coming out of the wall as close to the 45 as possible. Glue on a 22.5 degree elbow, glue on a new slip joint trap adapter. Now connect the horizontal arm and trap. Option 2 Cut the pie coming out of the wall as close to the 45 as possible. Glue on a hub, a piece of straight pipe, a 45 degree elbow then a new slip joint trap adapter. Now connect the trap. If option one works that's preferable because it's less fittings and less of an angle and less likely to clog. It may be a little awkward cutting the pipe but it's much better than cobbling it together with a bunch of fittings.